# MySQL: Joining Field

Tags: mysql

I have 3 fields in 1 table with data like this:

```
id | firstName | lastName  
1 | Budi | Arsana
```

and I want to execute a query to create the following output:

```
id | fullName  
1 | Budi Arsana
```

Notice that the output is combining the field `firstName` and `lastName` into `fullName`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) them with a space in between:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) AS fullName FROM table
```

Or use [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) if you had more than two fields to join:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(' ', firstName, lastName, otherName) AS fullName FROM table
```

Comment: wow thank you, this is first time i heard of concat function. *i'm new in learning MySQL :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the CONCAT function! It is very simple to use it. Just Google it!

Comment: i will be good if all the answer is here like michael do. only simple code to understand the concept how to use it :)